# Efficient implementation of large lookup values in Java

Tags: java, optimization, hashmap

I have this list of TCP/UDP port numbers and their string description:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

now this is in the form of an ***HashMap with portnumber as the key and string description as the value***. it might not be so big but i have to lookup for port description in real time when the packets are coming and as you can imagine, this requires efficient retrieval otherwise it slows down the processing considerably.

Initially i thought of implementing huge switch case/break logic or if, else if but that sounded too shabby so i came up with this hashMap.

Now i want to know does Java has something like caching mechanism to speed up if the queries are always the same? like mostly the queried ports will be 80, 443, 23, 22 etc and rarely other services type packets might arrive.

**My Options:**

- Should i make couple of else-if checks in the start for most
  common types and then revert to this hashMap if not found earlier
- Should i continue with this hashMap to do the search for me
- should i revert to some other clever way of doing this??

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HashMap has a guaranteed O(1) access time for get operations. The way you're doing it right now is perfect from any point of view.

Maintaining an if/else if structure would be error prone and useless in terms of speedup (for a large list it would actually be worse, with an O(n) asympt time).

Comment: The fact that it is O(1) is useful, but how long this constant time can be is what is important in this case...

Comment: What O(1) means is that looking up a value in a `HashMap` takes a constant amount of time and is not dependent on how many elements there are in the map.

Comment: I take your answer as the accepted one since i learned something from it, apart from just getting an answer, thanks

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Have you *measured* how long this takes ? I suspect that a lookup in a hash map with a reasonable number of buckets is going to be *negligible* compared to whatever else you're doing.

As always with these sort of questions, it's well worth measuring the supposed performance issue before working on it. *Premature optimisation is the root of all evil*, as [they say](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil/).

Comment: Ok thanks i didnt measure it, it was just a thought because on the contoller that i am implementing is kind of acting as server listening on specific port from like 100 something users (linux machines). So this hashMap will be queried by many threads in parallel, should i be taking care of synchronization here since im not modifying so i assume it won't matter, right... but thanks for the comment.

Comment: by the way, what if my hashMap is like 1 trillion entries, i mean off course then it will fail right?? just to know for understanding, i assume in that case @Peter's solution would still work, right?? PS: by fail i mean slow down considerably

Comment: @SpaceRocker See Tudor Vintilescu's answer. Since looking up a value does not depend on how many items there are in the map, it doesn't matter whether your map has 100 or 1 trillion items. (And it will not really have 1 trillion items, will it?).

Comment: Ok i got it, so to my understanding a list will also be slower then HashMap, isn't it because it has to linerly traverse before retrieving element, while hashMap compute direct position through constant O(1) time. Only problem will be memory bound, because if the size is too big then the swapping values over registers might slow down the operation. So is it true to say HashMap is even faster then List in java???

Comment: You cannot compare the two this way, simply because they are different tools for different purposes. A list is an _ordered_ linear collection interface. HashMap is a particular implementation for a _dictionary_ type object, which is non-linear and provides no order for the elements it contains (neither for keys, nor for values). Second, you are comparing an Interface, which doesn't specify an implementation, namely "List" to a particular implementation, namely HashMap, which particulizes the Map interface. There are many other differences. Long story short, HashMap should be ok in your case.

Answer (score 4):

> it slows down the processing considerably.

A lookup of a HashMap typically takes about 50 ns. Given reading from a socket with data typically takes 10,000 - 20,000 ns, I suspect this isn't the problem you think it is.

If you want really fast lookup use an array as this can be faster.

```
String[] portToName = new String[65536];
```

Comment: well thanks peter, this is even better since ports are sequential, great.